# Fourier analysis of an exponential function review

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I am working through and reviewing some of the examples presented on Fourier analysis from a Modern Digital and Analog Communication Systems book. In one of the examples, the author goes through the Fourier series of the exponential function $e^\frac{-t}{2}$ from $0$ to $\pi$.

My result of $a_0$ matches its result of $a_0=0.504$; however, my result for $a_n$ was $a_n=0.792\left(\frac2{1+16n^2}\right)$ and the book is $a_n=0.504\left(\frac2{1+16n^2}\right)$. I am trying to figure out, what am I doing wrong?

So doing integration by parts twice to find $a_n$, I get to the point in which I have:

$a_n=\frac2\pi\int_0^\pi$$e^\frac{-t}{2}\cos(2nt)dt=-\frac{1}{4\pi n^2}e^\frac{-t}{2}\cos(2nt)\vert_0^\pi-\frac{1}{8\pi n^2}\int_0^\pi$$e^\frac{-t}{2}\cos(2nt)dt$ , and then, I have:

$\left(\frac2\pi +\frac{1}{8\pi n^2}\right)\int_0^\pi$$e^\frac{-t}{2}\cos(2nt)dt=-\frac{1}{4\pi n^2}e^\frac{-t}{2}\cos(2nt)\vert_0^\pi$.

Doing some additional calculations I get:

$\left(\frac{16\pi n^2 + \pi}{8\pi^2 n^2}\right)\int_0^\pi$$e^\frac{-t}{2}\cos(2nt)dt=-\frac{1}{4\pi n^2}[e^\frac{-\pi}{2}\cos(2n\pi)-e^\frac{0}{2}\cos(0)]=-\frac{1}{4\pi n^2}[e^\frac{-\pi}{2}-e^0]$.

And finally:

$a_n=\frac2\pi\int_0^\pi$$e^\frac{-t}{2}\cos(2nt)dt=\frac{0.792}{4\pi n^2}\left[\frac{8\pi^2 n^2}{\pi(1+ 16n^2)}\right]=\frac{0.792}{4\pi}\left[\frac{8\pi}{(1+ 16n^2)}\right]=0.792\left(\frac{2}{1+ 16n^2}\right)$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you are doing integration by part?

Answer (score 0):

integrator program from wolfram side shows me following result

[image]

please check what is mistake

we may put following substitution

$y=-x/2$

that means that  $dy=-dx/2$

also  $x=-2*y$

so we have following form

$\int(-2*((e^y*cos(-2*n*2*y)))dy$

now  you can easily integrate by part

Comment: I already integrated by parts from the initial function, which takes me to do the same process twice. As I initially stated, the textbook example result is $a_n=0.504\left(\frac2{1+16n^2}\right)$.

Comment: if you getting same value twice,it means that you should divide  right side by two

Comment: are you integrating by  correct bounds?instead of $0$ and $\pi$ i meant

Comment: Yes! I am integrating between $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: what result did you get from integral?without putting value,did it coincides to  answer from mathworld site?

Comment: Yes, I get exactly the same result as the one in Wolfram.

Comment: then how u are getting different result?

Comment: Because I am evaluating the integral from $0$ to $\pi$. I got exactly the same result as Wolfram without doing the evaluation from $0$ to $\pi$. And even when I evaluated what I got from Wolfram from $0$ to $\pi$, I still don't get the same result as the example on the book. I am just going to wait until this graduate course starts and ask the class professor. I haven't been in school for almost 25 years, and I am trying to review the math before I start EE graduate classes. I should be able to pick it up again quick, though.

Comment: maybe there is mistake  in book